# How do I start the 'Diplomatic Immunity' quest?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I was playing Skyrim and I couldn't find the 24th stone of Barenziah. I looked it up on the Internet and I found out that it can be acquired while playing through the 'Diplomatic Immunity' quest.

But when I talk to Delphine in Riverwood to start it, she says I can only rent a room for 10 gold. How do I start it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Diplomatic Immunity" is part of the Main Quest Line. You must first do the main quest line first. After you do the quest "Horn of Jurgen Windcaller", talk to Delphine in Riverwood and say you want an attic room. Go to the room and wait for her to come and talk to you and a quest should start. After completing "A Blade in the Dark", "Diplomatic Immunity" should start.

Answer (score 2):

The Elder Scrolls Wiki has an entry on [Diplomatic Immunity](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Diplomatic_Immunity).

Diplomatic immunity is a main story quest. The prerequisite is listed in the info pane in the upper right of that wiki page. It's the quest "A Blade in the Dark".

Most Skyrim questions can be solved on the wiki. If you can't find the answer on the wiki, then tell us where you looked and what you found in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the thalmor embassy gate. Which is lock and requires a key. Bring a wooden plate. Then holding the plate in first person view, place the plate flat against the gate amd use whirlwind sprint to clip through the gate. And go directly to the kitchen to start the diplomatic immunity quest..

Comment: Does this work regardless of position in the mainquest?